# Scraper omitting a whole lead if a single item is missing out of four

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I made a scraper which is running fine but while pulling info from
a certain lead if it sees any item missing out of four then it skips
that lead and go on to the next lead.

the process so that it will pull the rest info irrespective
of one or two items are missing

```
Option Explicit
Const url As String = "http://www.yellowpages.com"
Const pageurl As String = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee%20Shops&geo_location_terms=AZ&page="
Sub yptest()
Dim http As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument, hmm As New HTMLDocument
Dim topics As Object, topic As Object, posts As Object, post As Object, lng As Object, mng As Object, nng As Object
Dim parse As Object, par As Object, pas As Object, pae As Object, sas As Object, jas As Object
Dim x As Long, zz As String, ss As String, y As Long, qas As Object, i As Long, t As Long

x = 2

for t = 1 to 10

http.Open "GET", pageurl & t, False
http.send
html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

Set topics = html.getElementsByClassName("info")

For y = 0 To topics.Length - 1
Set posts = topics(y).getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
zz = posts.getAttribute("href")
ss = url & Mid(zz, InStr(zz, ":") + 1)

    http.Open "GET", ss, False
    http.send
    hmm.body.innerHTML = http.responseText

Set parse = hmm.getElementsByClassName("sales-info")
Set sas = hmm.getElementsByClassName("address")
Set qas = hmm.getElementsByClassName("phone")
Set jas = hmm.getElementsByClassName("email-business")

    If parse.Length > 0 And sas.Length > 0 And qas.Length > 0 And jas.Length > 0 Then
        For i = 0 To parse.Length - 1
        Cells(x, 1) = parse(i).innerText
        Cells(x, 2) = sas(i).innerText
        Cells(x, 3) = qas(i).innerText
        Cells(x, 4) = jas(i).getAttribute("href")

        x = x + 1
        Next i
    End If
Next y
next t
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi mate, I see that you have already quite a few questions with answers and yet none were accepted, (not upvoted either, but you couldn't). Please accept the answers that helped you fixed your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
If parse.Length > 0 And sas.Length > 0 And qas.Length > 0 And jas.Length > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To parse.Length - 1
    Cells(x, 1) = parse(i).innerText
    Cells(x, 2) = sas(i).innerText
    Cells(x, 3) = qas(i).innerText
    Cells(x, 4) = jas(i).getAttribute("href")

    x = x + 1
    Next i
End If
```

To

```
If Parse.Length > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To Parse.Length - 1
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = Parse(i).innerText
    Next i
End If
If sas.Length > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To sas.Length - 1
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = sas(i).innerText
    Next i
End If
If qas.Length > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To qas.Length - 1
        Cells(i + 1, 3) = qas(i).innerText
    Next i
End If
If jas.Length > 0 Then
    For i = 0 To jas.Length - 1
        Cells(i + 1, 4) = jas(i).getAttribute("href")
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: You are the gem of a guy. It works as i expected it to. Thanks a trillion.

Comment: @ShahinIqbal : Did you see my comment on your question? Go to your profile and accept answers that helped you! ;)

Comment: I studied your rewritten portion and found an idea that is if in my mistaken portion of code i use "or" in place of "and" and place "on error resume next" before the last argument then it also work as i wanted. By the way, how to accept your answer as i don't know the process yet.

Comment: @ShahinIqbal : http://stackoverflow.com/tour and go to your profile to see your old questions